# Opening IDLE from another Python script with command line paramteters

Tags: python, python-idle

I am looking to open a Python script in edit mode in IDLE by passing in a directory from another Python script. I understand that I can use `os.system` to execute **idle.py** but I then don't know how to pass the appropriate `-e` parameter and get it to use a specific directory i.e. open **something.py** in diredtory **C:\Python** all from the original Python script.

Thanks for your help,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.call()`. By setting `shell = True`, the function treats the string as a literal shell command. Modify the paths as you see fit.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(r'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py -e C:\Python27\something.py',
                shell=True)
```

Comment: Should the not use forward slashes? For other operations, like `os.chdir`, an error is returned if forward slashes are not used, even on a Windows box.

Comment: I am afraid I think the rest of my program is so broken other errors are coming up before it even gets to this code. This is part of my first attempt at OOP programming so...

Comment: @fluffybonkers Well, if it does return a syntax error, flip the slashes.

Comment: Just tested in isolation. It works but it opens up multiple IDLE windows.

Comment: @fluffybonkers Try it without the -e?

Comment: @fluffybonkers I also just realized you may need `python` at the beginning of the call string but it seems like you got idle.py to run.